# OCR algorithm (GOCR) to 32F429IDISCOVERY board

Tags: algorithm, ocr, stm32, stm32f4discovery

I'm trying to implement an OCR algorithm (GOCR algorithm specifically) to 32F429IDISCOVERY board and I'm still getting nothing back...
I'm recording a image from OV7670 camera in RGB565 format to SDRAM of the board that is then converted to greyscale and passed to the algorithm itself.
From this and other forums I got the impression that GOCR is very good algorithm and it seemed to be working very well on PC but I just cant get it to work on the board.
Does anyone have some experience with implementing OCR or GOCR? I am not sure where the problem is because it beaves in a very wierd way. The code stops in different part of the algorithm almost every time...

Calling the OCR algorithm:

```
void ocr_algorithm(char *output_str) {
  job_t job1, *job; /* fixme, dont want global variables for lib */
  job=OCR_JOB=&job1;

  int linecounter;
  const char *line;

  uint8_t r,g,b;
  uint32_t n,i,buffer;
  char *p_pic;

  uint32_t *image = (uint32_t*) SDRAM_START_ADR;

  setvbuf(stdout, (char *) NULL, _IONBF, 0);    /* not buffered */

  job_init(job); /* init cfg and db */

  job_init_image(job); /* single image */

  p_pic = malloc(IMG_ROWS*IMG_COLUMNS);

  // Converting RGB565 to grayscale
  i=0;
  for (n = 0; n < IMG_ROWS*IMG_COLUMNS; n++) {
    if (n % 2 == 0){
        buffer = image[i] & 0xFFFF;
    }
    else{
        buffer = (image[i] >> 16) & 0xFFFF;
        i++;
    }

    r = (uint8_t) ((buffer >> 11) & 0x1F);
    g = (uint8_t) ((buffer >> 5) & 0x3F);
    b = (uint8_t) (buffer & 0x1F);

    // RGB888
    r = ((r * 527) + 23) >> 6;
    g = ((g * 259) + 33) >> 6;
    b = ((b * 527) + 23) >> 6;

    // Greyscale
    p_pic[n] = 0.299*r + 0.587*g + 0.114*b;
  }

  //read_picture;
  job->src.p.p = p_pic;
  job->src.p.x = IMG_ROWS;
  job->src.p.y = IMG_COLUMNS;
  job->src.p.bpp = 1;

  /* call main loop */
  pgm2asc(job);

  //print output
  strcpy(output_str, "");
  linecounter = 0;
  line = getTextLine(&(job->res.linelist), linecounter++);

  while (line) {
    strcat(output_str, line);
    strcat(output_str, "\n");

    line = getTextLine(&(job->res.linelist), linecounter++);
  }

  free_textlines(&(job->res.linelist));

  job_free_image(job);

  free(p_pic);
}
```

Comment: 1. what about sharing the code us to see ... 2. specify OCR lib if used any 3. are you sure the image is really taken  and converted to the right format ... 4. what does it mean code stops ? infinite loop? crash? exception? try to output some debug signals  like blinking LED or something so you see where exactly your code is ... for debug you can make single image store it an use only that so you have the same start point while debuging and not different image each compile&run ...

Comment: how much time the algo takes on PC? try to estimate how long it will take on your board (maybe you are just waiting too shortly)

Comment: Sorry...I just wanted to know if there will be some activity....
I know that I wait long enough, I can even see the progress when I am not debugging on LCD...
The GOCR algorithm is a standard v0.50 code and code gets stuck eaither before the conversion (I dont know were exacly) or just after it when results should be processed (store_boxtree_lines( job, job->cfg.mode );)
Stopping means that the program jumps into infinite loop (in startup_stm32f429_439xx.s)...
I have never experience something like this...I think its somehow related to memory (thats why I started to use SDRAM) but thats it...

Comment: Additionally I managed to run full algorithm few times but only with only one image (same image)...the output was wrong but I dont get why it is depended on the image...

Comment: comment in the ASM file describing the reason why the code jumps into infite loop:

This is the code that gets called when the processor receives an unexpected interrupt.  This simply enters an infinite loop, preserving the system state for examination by a debugger.

Comment: then you should get  the interrupt cause somehow (write own ISR handler and output on LCD or LED or whatever) my guess is division by zero, FPU error, stack/heap overflow/underflow or wrongly setted  memory timings (wait state) but I do not have experience with your platform so I am just guessing ...

Comment: yeah... I thought that the impleneting the algorithm will be easy... I dont think that I am that good to find where the mistake is...